# Transition a fixed position elements height

Tags: css

I have a `position: fixed;` navbar that I want to expand to the browser's height on click **over 0.2 seconds**.

You can see an example of the desired effect by clicking the "hamburger" on this page: http://iamwilliamstern.com/

**Example / what I've tried:**

Here is an example code pen where I try to do it:
http://codepen.io/donpinkus/pen/qaodzP

I add the class `.open` on click, which has the property `bottom: 0`. Bottom is an animatable property, but the issue is I haven't set a value for it to animate *from*. Is my only option to use JS to calculate what the `bottom` should be when it's "closed"?

I'm assuming there's a CSS only option to keep things smooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the "closed" div a `min-height: 1px`

Give the "open" div a `min-height: 100%`

Since you are **not** manually setting `height`, the "closed" nav will get its height from its content which is preferable to manually setting heights in CSS.

**Example here:** http://codepen.io/donpinkus/pen/amYvkL

```
div {
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  min-height: 20px; // This gets animated
}

.open {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Animating the `height` CSS property causes redrawing in browsers, which seriously hits performance later on.  You should stick to `transform` and `opacity` properties with animation and transition in CSS.

Comment: Thanks Ricky - that's solid advice.  Right now I'll take redraw over code complexity from manually setting an element's height, but if there is a solution that uses `transform` without needing magic numbers I'd use it :)

Comment: I'll work on a javascript solution to get the `nav` height and get this working.

Comment: I edited my answer, addressing the problem of manually setting the `translateY()` value. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead change bottom property add height for your initial div and change the same property in open class using 100 viewport height.

```
div {
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all .2s;
  height: 80px;

}

.open {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work when I try it - have you tried this successfully?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the `transform` CSS property to move your menu.

You will need to give this menu a `100%` height.

Then, in this demo, we will be using the `:target` CSS pseudo-class to style the menu once the user clicks the anchor. You can use javascript to toggle a class if you want to, just change the selector.

---

### CODE SNIPPET:

```css
.site__menu {
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: transform .2s linear;
  transform: translateY(85%);
}
.site__menu:target {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<section id="menu" class="site__menu">
  <header class="site__header">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#menu">Click me to expand</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section>
    <h1>
   Hello!
  </h1>
    <p>
      Some content here.
    </p>
  </section>
</section>
```

---

### EDIT:

Since the `header` element's height can change, the `transform` value will be hard to set.

That's why javascript will be used to get the `header` height and set the `translateY()` value.

The calculation is straight forward, using `calc()` CSS function.

```
transform: translateY(calc(containerHeight - headerHeight));
```

Since we want to cover our whole container we use:

```
transform: translateY(calc(100% - headerHeight));
```

Demo Example:

```
transform: translateY(calc(100% - 76px));
```

```js
var menu = $("#menu"),
  menuTrigger = $("#menu-trigger"),
  header = $(".site__header");

menuTrigger.on("click", function() {
  menu.toggleClass("open");
});

function getHeaderHeight() {
  var headerHeight = header.outerHeight(),
    result = headerHeight + "px";
  return result;
}

function transformMenu() {
  var translateValue = getHeaderHeight();
  menu.css("transform", "translateY(calc(100% - " + translateValue + "))");
}

transformMenu();

$(window).on("resize", function() {
  transformMenu();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.site__menu {
  background: dodgerblue;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: transform .2s linear;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
/* Utility Class */

.site__menu.open {
  transform: translateY(0) !important;
}
.site__nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
}
.menu__toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#spriteSheet {
  display: none;
}
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  stroke-width: 0;
  stroke: currentColor;
  fill: currentColor;
}
.icon-menu {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="menu" class="site__menu">
  <header class="site__header">
    <nav class="site__nav">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img src="http://fillmurray.com/40/40" alt="Fill Murray Logo">
        </li>
        <li>
          <a id="menu-trigger" class="menu__toggle">
            <svg class="icon icon-menu">
              <use xlink:href="#icon-menu"></use>
            </svg>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section>
    <h1>
   Hello!
  </h1>
    <p>
      Some content here.
    </p>
  </section>
</section>

<svg id="spriteSheet">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="icon-menu" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <title>menu</title>
      <path class="path1" d="M2 6h28v6h-28zM2 14h28v6h-28zM2 22h28v6h-28z"></path>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

---

> Without jQuery library:

```js
var menu = document.getElementById("menu"),
  menuTrigger = document.getElementById("menu-trigger"),
  header = document.querySelector(".site__header");

menuTrigger.addEventListener("click", function() {
  menu.classList.toggle("open");
});

function getHeaderHeight() {
  var headerHeight = header.offsetHeight + "px";
  result = headerHeight;
  return result;
}

function transformMenu() {
  var translateValue = getHeaderHeight();
  menu.style.transform = "translateY(calc(100% - " + translateValue + "))";
}

transformMenu();

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  transformMenu();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.site__menu {
  background: dodgerblue;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: transform .2s linear;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
/* Utility Class */

.site__menu.open {
  transform: translateY(0) !important;
}
.site__nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
}
.menu__toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#spriteSheet {
  display: none;
}
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  stroke-width: 0;
  stroke: currentColor;
  fill: currentColor;
}
.icon-menu {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<section id="menu" class="site__menu">
  <header class="site__header">
    <nav class="site__nav">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img src="http://fillmurray.com/40/40" alt="Fill Murray Logo">
        </li>
        <li>
          <a id="menu-trigger" class="menu__toggle">
            <svg class="icon icon-menu">
              <use xlink:href="#icon-menu"></use>
            </svg>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section>
    <h1>
   Hello!
  </h1>
    <p>
      Some content here.
    </p>
  </section>
</section>

<svg id="spriteSheet">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="icon-menu" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <title>menu</title>
      <path class="path1" d="M2 6h28v6h-28zM2 14h28v6h-28zM2 22h28v6h-28z"></path>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: This works - but there's a pretty serious downside:

You'll have to manually set the translateY() value anytime you change the size of content within the nav. So this is going to get messy quick (e.g. responsiveness, different text sizes, etc)

Comment: The link you provided just included a logo which size is not that big and an icon. You should specify that requirement in your question mate.

Answer (score -1):

here is mine solution: use min-height becouse css height is not "animatable"

http://codepen.io/KykooBG/pen/amYvJE

```
div {
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  min-height: 15px;
}

.open {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Ok, ignoring that you just copied my answer... the one thing you added is wrong, height IS animatable.

Comment: Sorry i didnt saw your post and just rushed to post this :D